# Is it possible to introduce custom step keyword in Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I would like to define steps using my custom keywords besides existing ones in Cucumber, i.e.:

> **As an** admin
>
> **I want to** perform something
>
> ...

Is it possible to define custom keywords in Cucumber besides Given/Then/When/And/But?

Comment: You can append steps with * instead of Given,Then.....

Comment: @Grasshopper If it was an answer, not comment, i would choose it. Looks like this feature is someting i was looking for. Why it is not so well documented? I can't see asterisk in the list of available keywords in wiki/reference documentation

Comment: Cucumber is open source and like most other similar projects suffers from lack of in-depth documentation. Only way to get at most corner uses is to go through the source. Though, I had come across this in a cucumber book written by one of the creators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'*' Keyword

'*' is very special. This defies the whole purpose of having Given, When, Then and all the other keywords. Basically Cucumber doesn’t care about what Keyword you use to define test steps, all it cares about what code it needs to execute for each step. That code is called a step definition. Just remember that all the keywords can be replaced by the * keyword and your test will just work fine.

Let’s see with example:

Feature: LogIn Action Test
Description: This feature will test a LogIn and LogOut functionality

Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
     Given User is on Home Page
     When User Navigate to LogIn Page
     And User enters UserName and Password
     Then Message displayed Login Successfully

**Using * Keyword**

Feature: LogIn Action Test
Description: This feature will test a LogIn and LogOut functionality

Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
     * User is on Home Page
     * User Navigate to LogIn Page
     * User enters UserName and Password
     * Message displayed Login Successfully

Given, When, Then, And can all be replaced with '*' keyword. And tests will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with QAF where you can provide [BDD Keywords Synonyms](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/BDD_Keywords_Synonyms.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own translation and thus introduce new words.

Gherkin is available in many languages, as far as I can understand well over 70. 
Adding a new language is pretty straight forward.

More information can be found at https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin

Answer (score 1):

The question I have for you is, why would you need to have **`As an`** or **`I want to`** as keywords at all?

These are used as context givers in most projects that I have worked on.

```
Feature: Register for an account
   As a potential customer
   I want to register for an account
   In order to book a flight

  Scenario: Particular Scenario
   Given I have not got an account
     And I want to access BDD Flights ticket booker
   When I register for an account
   Then I should be able to log in
```

The `Given`, `When`, `Then` keywords are for defining prerequisites, actions and outcomes respectively.

If you do want to add keywords in, then you can add your own translation of Gherkin to match these, as stated in Thomas Sundberg's answer, but in reality, you shouldn't need to do this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Are you facing any error?

Cucumber will execute the any steps that you have written in gherkin, provided if the step is defined in the `step_definitions` file. The gherkin scripts are basically for the non-technical team to understand the testing flow. There is no hard and fast rule on how it has to be written.

The basic idea to have gherkin is to have better understanding, and it is recommended that you write the test scripts which can be understood by someone who doesn't know about the system under test.

Comment: If I do not use any of mentioned keywords (i.e **Given**), the step definition gets ignred. I think Cucumber does not consider such lines as step definitions.

Comment: From documentation: `On the lines following a Feature, Scenario, Scenario Outline or Examples you can write anything you like, as long as no line starts with a key a keyword.`